# What is a full expression in C?

Tags: c, operators, expression, language-lawyer

I study C language from "C Primer Plus" book by Stephen Prata and it came to the point :

> "A full expression is one that’s not a subexpression of a larger
>   expression.Examples of full expressions include the expression in an
>   expression statement and the expression serving as a test condition
>   for a while loop"

I can't understand clearly what is the exact definition of full expressions and why the book considers test conditions are full expressions.

Could any one explain clearly what is meant by "Full Expression" and how can I  specify that an expression is full expression or not ?

Comment: "*Examples of full expressions include the expression in an expression statement*"...wat?

Comment: What the first phrase means, is that a full expression is maximal, and not a subexpression of another one.

Comment: Well, it is a point without a lot of bearing on your learning C. What he is trying to explain is a "full expression" would be the `while (condition) { /* ... stuff ... */ }` statement of the loop itself to the best of my read. It isn't a term you should lose sleep over, but do learn to identify the complete extent of a statement, etc.. See [C11 - §6.8 Statements and blocks](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8)

Comment: I don't know about the C book, but Stephen Prata is not highly regarded for his C++ Primer Plus book. See e.g .[this review for some details](https://accu.org/index.php?module=bookreviews&func=search&rid=1744).

Comment: It's an abridged - and therefore incorrect - copy from what the standard states. Burn the book.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 
I know Stephen Prata book in C++ isn't recommended .
But his book in C , in my opinion is highly recommended . I read 5 chapters till now . It has covered many topics in an amazing  explanation and nice format . The book covers data types and tricky topics about data and conversion between different types . Till now , Prata really wrote excellent book including tons of tricky details .

Comment: @smac89 There's this thing called an "expression statement". It's an expression, optionally followed by a semicolon, that fulfills the semantic role of a statement. That's saying that when you have an expression statement, the expression in it is a full expression. If you have, say, `if (x > 3) x = 2;` then `x = 2;` is an expression statement, hence the expression in it (`x = 2`) is a full expression.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

He's taken this straight from the C standard, example C11 6.8:

> A *full expression* is an expression that is not part of another expression or of a declarator.
>   Each of the following is a full expression: an initializer that is not part of a compound
>   literal; the expression in an expression statement; the controlling expression of a selection
>   statement (`if` or `switch`); the controlling expression of a `while` or `do` statement; each
>   of the (optional) expressions of a `for` statement; the (optional) expression in a return
>   statement. There is a sequence point between the evaluation of a full expression and the
>   evaluation of the next full expression to be evaluated.

Some examples would be:

`if(x)`

`for(x; y; z)`

`return x;`

where x y and z are *full expressions*.

*Full expression* is a language grammar term and not really something a C programmer needs to know about. It is only relevant to "language lawyers" and those making compilers or static analysers. The C standard speaks of *statements*, *blocks* and *full expressions*.

What the programmer might need to know is the last sentences of the above cited text, which means that after a full expression, all side effects of that expression are carried out. So if I write code such as `if(i++) printf("%d", i);` then I know that the `i++` has been carried out before the printf line.

It may however be quite useful to know these dry grammar terms when reading compiler errors. Such as the infamous "statement missing", that most likely means, in plain English, that you've forgotten a semicolon.

Comment: Link [C11 - §6.8 Statements and blocks](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8)

Comment: @Abd-ElrahmanMohamed Type it in Google and the answer shall be revealed. It is a language feature that was introduced in C 20 years ago - basically it is a local scope, anonymous object. Any decent C programming book will explain it.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the statement below

```
a = b + c;
```

`a = b + c` is an expression which is not a subexpression of any larger expression. This is called full expression.
`b + c` is a subexpression of the larger expression `a = b + c` therefore it is not a full expression. `b` is also a subexpression for the full expression `a = b + c` and subexpression `b + c`.