# Rvalue References in C++ with an easy example

Tags: c++

Im trying to understand what exactly `Rvalue References` are.
Everywhere I look they have examples to something called `Perfect forwarding` which sounds too complicated.

I just want a clear basic example of what Rvalue References are and see if they get used outside of the topics like Perfect forwarding.

I have read:

> An lvalue is an expression that refers to a memory location and allows us to take the address of that memory location via the & operator. An rvalue is an expression that is not an lvalue

So is it correct to say:

```
An Rvalue Reference is a Reference to something that is not in the memory? Maybe it's in a register?
```

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int&& a = 50;  
   int b = 60;

  return 0;
}
```

`50` is technically not in memory yet but `a` is a reference to it? is `b` any different than `a`?

Where else (which is easily explainable) can this be used?

Comment: The reason `int&& a = 50;` works isn't very easy to explain. You can do `&a` and get a valid `int*` which shows that `a` actually refers to something that exists somewhere in memory. This isn't a good example of when rvalue references are useful. Have you been introduced to "move semantics" yet?

Comment: `50` isn't in memory yet when you are assigning it' reference to `a`, it's just  an rvalue number. try  `int& a = 50;` and it fails.

Comment: Yes `int& a = 50;` fails but it's different from `int&& a = 50;`. With `int&&` there is actually a temporary `int` that is sneakily created with the value `50` and `a` refers to that object and extends the object's lifetime. You'll get the same thing with `const int & a = 50;`.

Comment: Related question : [Why can I assign value to rvalue reference which refers to literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51985202/why-can-i-assign-value-to-rvalue-reference-which-refers-to-literals).

Comment: why does `const int & a = 50;` work? why const makes a difference

Comment: There's an explicit rule that says you can bind a `const` lvalue reference to an rvalue. This rule predates the introduction of rvalue references, it was introduced in a time where it was useful to have such a reference but when rvalue references weren't invented yet. The reason non-`const` references were excluded from the rule is because, at the time, it didn't make sense to try to change an rvalue like 50. It still doesn't, but because of how rvalue references are used for move semantics, you can't ban it outright.

Comment: Thanks, so `int&& a` creates a temp variable and whenever i modify `a` it actually changes that temp variable? VS `int b` just creates a normal visible variable?

Comment: Yes **in this case**. References don't usually create or extend the life time of temporaries, only in some cases. You can [read about it here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary). Most of the time, when you use references, it's to refer to objects that already exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, whether or not something resides in the memory or in a register is not defined by the standard. You don't need to think about it. For you, all objects work as if they were in memory. Under the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if), your compiler can put some of them into the registers, as long as it doesn't affect how your program works.

Yes, you can obtain addresses of lvalues (except bitfields) and not rvalues, but that's a language design choice rather than a technical limitation (most of the time it would make no sense, so it's not allowed). [Value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) (lvalues vs rvalues) have nothing to do with how things are stored in memory.

> Im trying to understand what exactly Rvalue References are

Rvalue references are similar to lvalue references. The primary difference is what you can initialize them with. Rvalue references must be initialized with rvalues, and lvalue references must be initialized with lvalues (as an exception, `const` lvalue references are allowed to bind to rvalues).

`int&& a = 50;` works because `50` is an `int` and a temporary object. (Usually "a temporary object" is a synonym for "an rvalue", but [not always](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).)

This case is a bit tricky, because temporaries as normally destroyed at the end of [full-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880037/what-is-a-full-expression-in-c) (roughly, when the line of code they were created in finishes executing). But here, the lifetime of `50` is [extended](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) because it's bound to a reference.

> is b any different than a?
>
> ```
> int&& a = 50;  
> int b = 60;
> ```

Because of the lifetime extension - no, they're equivalent. Maybe there's some obscure difference between them, but I can't think of any.

Comment: Thanks, so then is it correct to say `An Rvalue Reference is a Reference to something that does not have an address`?

Comment: @Josh It's close, but not entirely correct. You can write `&a` and get the address of the thing that `a` refers to. You could say that rvalue references *can be initialized with* things that you can't take addresses of.

Comment: @Josh Yes, `a` is an lvalue and `50` is an rvalue. The thing is, a value category (lvalue vs rvalue) is a property of an expression, not of an object. Expressions refer to objects. Let's say you do `int &&a = 42; std::cout << a;` Here, `42` and the second `a` refer to the same object (to the temporary `int`), but one is an rvalue and the other is not.

Comment: So to be clear, C++ will create a `hidden` variable in memory and point my variable to it, whenever I change that variable, the hidden variable is changed?

Comment: Ahhh, so that all Rvalue is, a hidden variable that compiler creates for me and is modified during runtime.

Comment: @Josh I think you may be misunderstanding value categories. They refers to *an expression* not an object. So `50` is an rvalue expression and `a` is an lvalue expression. The hidden variable is not an expression and can't appear in an expression so it doesn't have a value category.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux but it is true that Rvalue is, a hidden variable and `int&&` as an example will point to it?

Comment: @Josh No. Those temporary objects created for your reference don't have value categories and rvalue certainly doesn't mean "temporary object". The expression that was used to initialize them does. An rvalue describes one of two kinds of expressions. Either a [prvalue expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue) or an [xvalue expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#xvalue) You can follow those links for lists of what is and what is not an rvalue. It's a common mistake to think value categories describe objects but they don't.

Comment: Alright well we are back at where we started. What is Rvalue Reference then, I don't want to get into too much detail, ELI5 type, is Rvalue a hidden thing tat compiler makes up? doesn't matter if the `thing` is object or expression, which I don't even know what they are.

Comment: @Josh I don't think one can explain this without getting into details, C++ is tricky. :| Those "hidden variables" as you call them are called *temporaries* (short for *temporary objects*, the word [variable](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/variables) has a slightly different meaning). *"object or expressions, which I don't even know what they are"* Objects, roughly speaking, are actual pieces of memory. When your program runs, it creates/modifies/destroys them on the way. Expression, on the other hand, is a grammatical term. Expressions exist only in the source code.

Comment: got it, so if we refer to them as just `temporaries`, then rvalues are liked to them, i.e in `int&& a = 50 `, `a` points to a temporary? does the temporary have a value and it's 50?

Comment: If you want a real world analogy... Let's say you have a dog named Rex. The dog itself is an object, because it actually exists. But if you write the word "Rex" on a piece of paper, this word will be an expression. Expressions *refer* to objects.

Comment: @Josh Yep, there's a temporary there with value `50`. Rvalue reference `a` points to the temporary.

Comment: @Josh The `50` (the number that's written in the source code) is an rvalue expression referring to that temporary. After writing `int &&a = 50;`, the name `a` (which acts an expression) can be used to refer to the same temporary, but `a` (the expression) is an lvalue. Yep, even though they are called "rvalue references", names of rvalue references as lvalues.

Comment: appreciate your help.

Comment: @Josh You're welcome. I hope I didn't make you more confused that you were before. D:

Comment: @Josh This might be helpful: https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/variables https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions